# Get auto growth settings for all Databases in instance

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to get auto growth settings of all DBs in my all SQL instances. Found a script, but it is giving me an error for some of the values, which I am unable to fix

https://raresql.com/2013/02/19/sql-server-best-way-to-check-all-database-autogrowth-settings/

```
SELECT
S.[name] AS [Logical Name]
,S.[file_id] AS [File ID]
, S.[physical_name] AS [File Name]
,CAST(CAST(G.name AS VARBINARY(256)) AS sysname) AS [FileGroup_Name]
,CONVERT (varchar(10),(S.[size]*8)) + ' KB' AS [Size]
,CASE WHEN S.[max_size]=-1 THEN 'Unlimited' ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CONVERT(bigint,S.[max_size])*8) +' KB' END AS [Max Size]
,CASE s.is_percent_growth WHEN 1 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),S.growth) +'%' ELSE Convert(VARCHAR(10),S.growth*8) +' KB' END AS [Growth]
,Case WHEN S.[type]=0 THEN 'Data Only'
WHEN S.[type]=1 THEN 'Log Only'
WHEN S.[type]=2 THEN 'FILESTREAM Only'
WHEN S.[type]=3 THEN 'Informational purposes Only'
WHEN S.[type]=4 THEN 'Full-text '
END AS [usage]
,DB_name(S.database_id) AS [Database Name]
FROM sys.master_files AS S
LEFT JOIN sys.filegroups AS G ON ((S.type = 2 OR S.type = 0)
AND (S.drop_lsn IS NULL)) AND (S.data_space_id=G.data_space_id)
```

Error

**Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.**

I can sense somewhere the returned value does not fit as INT and I tried to cast big values as bigint, but still same error

```
SELECT
S.[name] AS [Logical Name]
,S.[file_id] AS [File ID]
, S.[physical_name] AS [File Name]
,CAST(CAST(G.name AS VARBINARY(256)) AS sysname) AS [FileGroup_Name]
,CONVERT (varchar(20),cast((S.[size]*8) as bigint)) + ' KB' AS [Size]
,CASE WHEN S.[max_size]=-1 THEN 'Unlimited' ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),CAST((S.[max_size])*8 as bigint)) +' KB' END AS [Max Size]
,CASE s.is_percent_growth WHEN 1 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),S.growth) +'%' ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CAST((S.growth*8) as bigint)) +' KB' END AS [Growth]
,Case WHEN S.[type]=0 THEN 'Data Only'
WHEN S.[type]=1 THEN 'Log Only'
WHEN S.[type]=2 THEN 'FILESTREAM Only'
WHEN S.[type]=3 THEN 'Informational purposes Only'
WHEN S.[type]=4 THEN 'Full-text '
END AS [usage]
,DB_name(S.database_id) AS [Database Name]
FROM sys.master_files AS S
LEFT JOIN sys.filegroups AS G ON ((S.type = 2 OR S.type = 0)
AND (S.drop_lsn IS NULL)) AND (S.data_space_id=G.data_space_id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. The casting is now done before the * 8.

```
SELECT S.[name] AS [Logical Name],
       S.[file_id] AS [File ID],
       S.[physical_name] AS [File Name],
       CAST(CAST(G.name AS VARBINARY(256)) AS sysname) AS [FileGroup_Name],
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), CAST(S.[size] AS BIGINT) * 8) + ' KB' AS [Size],
       CASE
           WHEN S.[max_size] = -1 THEN
               'Unlimited'
           ELSE
               CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), CAST(S.[max_size] AS BIGINT) * 8) + ' KB'
       END AS [Max Size],
       CASE S.is_percent_growth
           WHEN 1 THEN
               CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), S.growth) + '%'
           ELSE
               CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(S.growth AS BIGINT) * 8) + ' KB'
       END AS [Growth],
       CASE
           WHEN S.[type] = 0 THEN
               'Data Only'
           WHEN S.[type] = 1 THEN
               'Log Only'
           WHEN S.[type] = 2 THEN
               'FILESTREAM Only'
           WHEN S.[type] = 3 THEN
               'Informational purposes Only'
           WHEN S.[type] = 4 THEN
               'Full-text '
       END AS [usage],
       DB_NAME(S.database_id) AS [Database Name]
FROM sys.master_files AS S
    LEFT JOIN sys.filegroups AS G
        ON (
               (
                   S.type = 2
                   OR S.type = 0
               )
               AND (S.drop_lsn IS NULL)
           )
           AND (S.data_space_id = G.data_space_id);
```

Comment: Yes that works .. thanks